# JBoss error: org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) keycloak

Tags: django, postgresql, keycloak

i am trying to integrate postgres db with keycloak in docker. i updated standalone.xml with postgres drive. still getiing error

> "[org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot
>   Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([" . anyone
>   have idea what it failing.

--------------dockerfile-------

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:latest
ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_USER admin
ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD admin

COPY standalone.xml /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

COPY init.sh
USER root
ENTRYPOINT [ "bash",  "./init.sh" ]
```

-------------------------------init.sh-----------

```
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1010
```

-----------------------------docker-compose-----------

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=postgres
      - DB_NAME=idm_keycloak_demo
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASS=admin
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  keycloak:
    restart: always
    build: ./keycloak
    environment:
      - KC_PG_HOST=postgres 
      - POSTGRES_DATABASE=idm_keycloak_demo
      - KC_PG_USER=postgres
      - KC_PG_PASSWORD=admin
    depends_on:
      - postgres          
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
         POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
         POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'admin'
         POSTGRES_DB: 'idm_keycloak_demo'
```

-----------standalone.xml------------

```
<datasources>
                 <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
               <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/idm_keycloak_demo</connection-url>
                   <driver>postgresql</driver>
                   <pool>
                       <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                   </pool>
                   <security>
                       <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                       <password>admin</password>
                   </security>
               </datasource>
                <drivers>
                   <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql.jdbc">
                      <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm also getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was happening because I did not create a database specified in KeyCloak configuration in advance.

From what I see from your docker-compose that is not your case, but I will still leave this answer there because I struggled with this for a long time and this question is almost everything I found on a topic, maybe it will help somebody.